# Bash array within a double loop (while/for/if)

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, conditional-statements

I am parsing a number of files and copying the lines matching two conditions to a new file. The script behaves differently depending on the size of the array:

```
while read pdb ; do
# for c in "${chain[@]}" ; do
for ((c=0; c<${#chain[@]}; c++)) ; do
if [ ${#chain[@]} -eq 1 ] && [ "$(echo "$pdb" | cut -c1-4)" == "ATOM" ] && [ "$(echo "$pdb" | cut -c22-23)" == "${chain[$c]}" ] ; then
echo "$pdb" >> ../../properpdb/${pdbid}_${chain[$c]}.pdb
fi
done
done < ${pdbid}.pdb
```

This works, but only if I remove the last condition (the one referring to a particular array element). I have tried many different syntaxes (double square brackets, using ${c} rather than ${chain[$c]}, etc.) to no avail.

This is ${pdbid}.pdb

```
ATOM     13  CA  SER A   9     107.761  75.138  27.465  1.00 24.92           C  
ATOM     14  C   SER A   9     107.081  73.915  26.851  1.00 21.25           C  
ATOM     15  O   SER A   9     105.984  73.987  26.313  1.00 24.75           O  
ATOM     16  CB  SER A   9     107.956  76.218  26.399  1.00 30.66           C
```

This is one of the arrays:

```
chain=(A)
```

Debug:

```
+ read pdb
+ for c in '"${chain[@]}"'
+ '[' 1 -eq 1 ']'
++ echo 'ATOM   1916  CZ3 TRP B  43     -15.691  19.837  49.406  1.00 12.45           C'
++ cut -c1-4
+ '[' ATOM == ATOM ']'
++ echo 'ATOM   1916  CZ3 TRP B  43     -15.691  19.837  49.406  1.00 12.45           C'
++ cut -c22-23
+ [[ A == B  ]]
+ read pdb
```

Everything seems to be right except that the last condition is not surrounded by single quotes. There is no output even if A == A. If I remove that condition, it works.

Comment: Can you provide a piece of ${pdbid}.pdb so we can try it out?

Comment: `set -vx` or change shebang to `/bin/bash -x` to turn on debugging. Check output to see that everything is expanded as intended (probably the quoting)... See [bash debugging](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html)

Comment: Description updated with input samples and debug info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you cut two characters in the test expression, it should be:

```
if [ ${#chain[@]} -eq 1 ] && \
   [ $(echo "$pdb" | cut -c1-4) == "ATOM" ] && \
   [ $(echo "$pdb" | cut -c22-22) == "${chain[$c]}" ]; then     
    echo "$pdb" >> ${pdbid}_${chain[$c]}.pdb
fi
```

You should use cut -c22-22 rather than -c22-23. I removed the double quotes around the command substitution so it will also remove white spaces for you.

Comment: I don't think that's true. The parentheses will start a new subshell and a new "quoting scope". As an example, try this with and without outer quotes: `echo "$(echo "foo    bar")"` (make sure you use multiple spaces between foo and bar: markdown won't let me do it here)

Comment: @glenn you are probably right. The strange thing is that if double quote is used around command substitution, the solution won't work. Maybe it's a bug from bash. The problematic line is `[ "$(echo "$pdb" | cut -c22-23)" == "${chain[$c]}" ]`

Comment: however, the reason it works is not because you can't mix quotes (you can), but the side-effect of not quoting is to drop any leading spaces, and most likely the value of ${chain[0]} does not have leading spaces.